# Downsampling, AUROC and accuracy equal

Tags: accuracy, resampling

I am using downsampling to create perfectly balanced classes in my target feature. I have found that accuracy is exactly equal to the AUROC score. I was thinking that this is because I've used downsampling, is this possible or is it just a coincidence?